# How to use with_nested on 2 dicts to get value in ansible?

Tags: loops, dictionary, ansible

I have the following 2 maps setup

```
prefix_color:
  eu_: "blue"
  us_: "red"

country_shade:
  sweden: "light"
  belgium: "dark"
```

I want to loop through both maps in the same manner one can do with `with_nested` in ansible but I need to access both the key and value from both dicts.

Essentially what I need is something like this

```
- name: loop
  debug:
    msg: "key: {{ item[0].key + item[1].key }}, value: {{ item[0].value + item[1].value }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ prefix_color }}"
    - "{{ country_shade }}"
```

The above does not work as only the keys are available with `with_nested` and `with_dict` does not allow for more than 1 dictionary.

How does one go about this? It seems that it should be something simple to do given that both concepts of nested loops and dictionaries exists in ansible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dictsort](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#dictsort) to convert dictionaries into lists:

```
- name: loop
  debug:
    msg: "key: {{ item[0] + item[2] }}, value: {{ item[1] + item[3] }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ prefix_color | dictsort }}"
    - "{{ country_shade | dictsort  }}"
```

In your setup original keys will be at even indices, and values – at uneven.

Comment: Thank you. It works however I think this is something that is missing in Ansible and should be properly addressed